# Persist execution of stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

How I could persist the execution of the second stored procedure(dbo.Test2) even when the first one fails?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test4]
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @RC INT

    EXEC @RC =  dbo.Test1

    EXEC @RC =  dbo.Test2

END TRY

/*
    Exception handler
*/
BEGIN CATCH

    IF xact_state() <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    DECLARE
        @ErrorMessage   varchar(max) = error_message(),
        @ErrorSeverity  int          = error_severity(),
        @ErrorState     int          = error_state()

    -- add to stack trace
    SET @ErrorMessage = [dbo].[fnStackTrace](error_number(), error_procedure(), error_line(), @ErrorMessage)

    -- push the trace up the stack
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: implement **EXEC @RC =  dbo.Test2** in catch also after printing error

Answer (score 0):

For this you should keep both the Procedures in two different transaction.

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test4]
AS
begin
     DECLARE
         @ErrorMessage   varchar(max),
         @ErrorSeverity  int         ,
         @ErrorState     int         

    Begin Transaction
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @RC INT

        EXEC @RC =  dbo.Test1

        commit transaction
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        IF xact_state() <> 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        set
            @ErrorMessage  = error_message(),
            @ErrorSeverity = error_severity(),
            @ErrorState    = error_state()

        -- add to stack trace
        SET @ErrorMessage = [dbo].[fnStackTrace](error_number(), error_procedure(), error_line(), @ErrorMessage)

        -- push the trace up the stack
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

    END CATCH;
    begin transaction
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @RC =  dbo.Test2
        commit transaction
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        IF xact_state() <> 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        set
            @ErrorMessage    = error_message(),
            @ErrorSeverity   = error_severity(),
            @ErrorState      = error_state()


        SET @ErrorMessage = [dbo].[fnStackTrace](error_number(), error_procedure(), error_line(), @ErrorMessage)


        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

    END CATCH;
end
GO
```